# Change "linked" references to objects in java

Tags: java, object, pointers, reference

I am currently implementing a Vehicle Routing algorithm (the Savings heuristic). Here I have a node class consisting of three references:

1. a node's predecessor in a tour (being a reference to another node)
2. a node's successor (being a reference to another node)
3. a tour class

```
class Node{
 Node pred;
 Node succ;
 Tour t;
}

class Tour{
 // Some data
}
```

Throughout the code I want to change the tour reference in the following manner:

```
Node a = new Node();
a.t = new Tour();
Node b = new Node();
b.pred = a;
b.t = b.pred.t; // the tour of b is the same as of a, and a reference
a.succ = b;

// ... some more stuff

Node c = new Node();
c.t = new Tour();
c.pred = a;
a.succ = c;
a.t = c.t; // "adds" a to the tour of c. Changes the reference to t in a and c, but not in b :(
```

After running the last line of code, the tour of b still points to the original tour of a (it remains in the memory). I would have assumed that, since it is a reference from the beginning, it now points to c.t

Is there any chance of achieving what I desire without manually updating the references of all of a's successors?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A reference is also just a value. When multiple objects `A` and `B` reference another object `C` and e.g. `A` changes `C`, then the change will be visible to `B`. When you change the reference from `A` to `C` to another value, then you've just changed a value, so `B` will still reference `C`.

Comment: To add to what akuzminykh said, "references are just values" they work like primitives.  If I declare that "Tour" is just an `int`, and I assign the value `a.t = 1` and `b.t = a.t` and then later I assign `a.t = c.t` with some other value, `b.t` does not magically "track" the value of `a.t`.  It still has its old value of 1, and it won't change until you assign it a different one.

Comment: P.S. Does anyone have a "classic algorithm" that uses this kind of assignment?  The kind that works like programming, where values are copied to other values at the time they are copied, and then new values are assigned later in the algorithm.  It feel like there must be something, but nothing comes to mind.